# How to get nth character in a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've a string (let's say "Hello World") and I want to save the first characters of it in different variables (ex. character1 = "H", character2 = "e"...).

How do I get the nth character in the string?

Thanks!

Bonus: 
How could I do it with Python? Would it be better than doing it client-side?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use the [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/string/charat) method.  As far as client or server, it depends on the context.  But you should not trust client input.

Answer (score 67):

### Let me summarize the possibilities

given:

```
var string = "HAI";
/* and */
var index = 1; // number ∈ [0..string.length), rounded down to integer
```

- `string.charAt(index)` returns `"A"` ([preferred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt))
- `string[index]` returns `"A"` ([non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access))
- `string.substring(index, index+1)` returns `"A"` ([over-complex solution but works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring))
- `string.substr(index, 1)` returns `"A"` ([non-standard approach to above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr))

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is cross-browser safe, but you can use array-like indexing:

```
"Hello"[0] -> "H"
```

The syntax is exactly the same in Python.