# Why is '\u{1D11E}'.charAt(0) not equal to '\u{1D11E}'?

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf

When I'm trying to evaluate this expression in console I have `false` as result, why?

```js
console.log('\u{1D11E}'.charAt(0) === '\u{1D11E}')
```

Comment: Please fix your question. That's just a unformatted line of invalid syntax.

Comment: Because charAt can only handle UTF-16,

Comment: Because `charAt()` originally was designed to support BMP only, and the character you gave does not belong to BMP. Check [this section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt#Getting_whole_characters) for details (and a remedy).

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46157867/3650856. You comapre an unicode character on right side with non-unicode character on left side. charAt(0) will break down unicode character as it is longer byte wise. Therefore they will not be same value, only same type.

Comment: @raina77ow  another option is use `Array.from` on the string, and index into this.  Not sure why MDN didn't mention that.

Comment: Also more information here: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple console.log would show you the problem

```js
console.log('\u{1D11E}'.charAt(0))
console.log('\u{1D11E}')
console.log('\u{1D11E}'.charAt(0) === '\u{1D11E}')
```

As you can see they don't give the same result, that's because `charAt` only handles [`UTF-16` code **units**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt). See code snippet on same source on how to handle UTF-16 characters (also on other planes, so with code point > 65535).

Comment: Hi, but when '\u{1D11E}'.chartAt(0) === '\uD834' and the outcome is true

Comment: @JsonPrime same idea, console.log each one of them and you'll see why. They both return �

Comment: Ok , since they both return � , so result of '\u{1D11E}'.chartAt(0) === '\uD834' is true , am i right ?

Comment: @JsonPrime it's `charAt` not `chartAt`, and yes

Comment: The explanation is wrong: `'\u{1D11E}` is a UTF-16 character (or better a UTF-16 code point). MDN uses **code unit** (which it is a seldom used notation in Unicode). In this case, the `charAt(0)` gives a code unit, which it is a surrogate, so not a valid UTF-16 code point (or character).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi feel free to edit my answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Hi , what Im get from your feedback is `\u{1D11E}` is a UTF16 character which `charAt(0)` can handle but the problem is `\u{1D11E}` does not have a valid code point ?

Comment: @JsonPrime: no/maybe. `\u{1D11E}` is a valid code point, `charAt` doesn't necessarily return valid code points (just code unit, which may be half of code point, for code points > `0xFFFF`). If you need to get the valid code point, you should check the example/fix in the linked MDN page.

Answer (score 2):

`'\u{1D11E}'` is a string consisting of a single Unicode **codepoint** `U+1D11E`.  Strings are encoded in UTF-16 format.  So each `char` in the string is a UTF-16 **code unit**.  Thus `charAt()` returns a code unit, not a codepoint.

`U+1D11E` is encoded in UTF-16 as `0xD834 0xDD1E`, so the string `'\u{1D11E}'` is actually `'\uD834\uDD1E'`, thus:

```
'\u{1D11E}'.charAt(0) === '\u{1D11E}' // false
// aka: '\uD834' === '\u{1D11E}'
```

and

```
'\u{1D11E}'.charAt(0) === '\uD834' // true
// aka: '\uD834' === '\uD834'
```